# External Javascript files in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am basing a website on an [old tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/10/03/multibox-menu/), which uses 3 external  [js files](https://github.com/jakubsuplicki/multibox_menu_nuxt_js/tree/master/static/js). I am not able to recreate this using nuxtjs.

First, I tried to include the js files before the  tag.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true },
      { src: 'js/TweenMax.min.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true },
      { src: 'js/demo.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true }
    ]
  },
```

This works on initial page load. However, as soon as I change the page, the js files are ignored.

---

After some research, I tried to include the files as a plugin, to avoid ssr.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
plugins: [
    { src: "plugins/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js", mode: 'client' },
    { src: "plugins/TweenMax.min.js", mode: 'client' },
    { src: "plugins/demo.js", mode: 'client' }
  ],
```

This gave me multiple error messages (amongst other things: `'Cannot read property addEventListener of null`).

This is a very small project with a lot of time pressure, so any kind of help would be highly appreciated!

---

**Update:**

[Original GitHub repository](https://github.com/codrops/MultiboxMenu/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution -  steps to follow:**

---

Add `base.css` to static > css folder, and also add all of the `js` files to static > js folder and then reference everything in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'css/base.css' }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: 'js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true },
      { src: 'js/TweenMax.min.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true },
      { src: 'js/demo.js', type: 'text/javascript', body: true, defer: true }
   ]
```

Add all of the images to static > img folder and edit the `base.css` in order to reference images in `base.css` - write (wherever the images are referenced (2 places)): `url('../img/1.jpg')`

In the Vue template, copy-paste the `HTML` as-is.

When it comes to referencing images in the Vue template you would simply do:

```
<div class="background" style="background-image: url(img/1.jpg)"></div>
```

That is it. It should work just fine.

---

I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jakubsuplicki/multibox_menu_nuxt_js) so you can have a look and see how I have done it.

---

You can also view it live on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-shape-pwrw5).

Comment: Thank you for your response! It looks better than before. However, I am still getting some error messages, like TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, or TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Which makes me suspicious about this being loaded on the client...

Comment: Can you try importing it one by one like that and see if there is a particular file that causes this issue, please (possibly `demo.js`)?

Comment: Yes, it is the demo.js file. Everything else works perfectly with your method.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you! I added the entire content of the file to my question.

Comment: I managed to make it fully functional with Nuxt.js (Vue.js & Node.js). Please have a look at the edited answer. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. It is exactly what I already described in  my question. As described there: 'This works on initial page load. However, as soon as I change the page, the js files are ignored.' Probably somebody else can profit from this, so I will accept it anyway. Thank you so much for all your effort!

Comment: The original repo was created for a single page scenario so there is a problem with these `js` files as they will be most likely referring to the specific elements that might not exist on other pages. It could mean that `js` files would also have to be edited if you wanted to re-use the functionality across the application and not just that specific page.

Answer (score -1):

To integrate bootstrap within antd-ui for my nuxt js project, this is what worked for me:

in nuxt.config.js, add the following

1. add boostrap css files in css folder within assets folder:

   css: [
   'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css',
   '~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
   '~/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css',
   '~/assets/css/bootstrap-utilities.min.css'
   ],
2. add boostrap js files in js folder within static folder:

   plugins: [
   '@/plugins/antd-ui',
   {src: '~/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', mode:'client'},
   ],

This worked for me